# Download zero byte attachment with Gmail API

Tags: .net, vb.net, gmail-api

I have some mails with empty files attachments, I can not download it because Gmail API does not assign AttachmentId. Given the already designed processes flow, I need to download those files and save them, even if are empty.

The code to get attachments was taken from [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get), has been translated to vb.net  and modified a little:

```vb
Try
Dim message As Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message = service.Users.Messages.Get(userId, messageId).Execute()
Dim parts As IList(Of Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.MessagePart) = message.Payload.Parts

For Each part As Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.MessagePart In parts
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(part.Filename) And Regex.IsMatch(part.Filename, searchedFile) And Not part.Body.AttachmentId Is Nothing Then
        Dim attId As String = part.Body.AttachmentId
        Dim attachPart As Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.MessagePartBody = service.Users.Messages.Attachments.Get(userId, messageId, attId).Execute()

        ' Converting from RFC 4648 base64-encoding
        ' see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history
        Dim attachData As String = attachPart.Data.Replace("-", "+")
        attachData = attachData.Replace("_", "/")

        Dim data As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(attachData, 0, attachData.Length)

        If Not Directory.Exists(outputDir) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDir)
        End If

        File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(outputDir, part.Filename), data)

    End If
Next

Catch ex As Exception
' ErrorHandler(ex)
End Try
```

There is a Nothing value test, just to avoid GoogleApiException.

Is there a way to download empty files with Gmail API?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't download it, just create an empty file and pretend you downloaded it.

Comment: @lucas you are right, the files are plain text, so file size are zero bytes, another format like xlsx or zip are at least 1kb size when are empty and for those files, Gmail API generates the AttachmentID. Thanks